# What is geometry, algebra, or topology?

Tags: general-topology, geometry

I have trouble grasping the notion of geometry, algebra, and topology. An example is when someone might say, "I study the geometry of jet spaces" or "I study the lie algebras". What does it mean for a problem to be geometric, or algebraic, or topological? What separates an algebraic problem from a geometric or topological one? I feel like if I better understood these words I would understand the big picture more. There are probably more to add besides geometry, algebra, and topology but I couldn't think of any more.

Comment: analysis is one of the other "big" ones.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a bit simplified, but it's my view on these areas:

- Geometric studies consider planes and curves, and how they bend and twist.
- Algebraic studies consider structures of arithmetic and of symmetry.
- Topologic studies consider continuity of functions.
- Analysis studies differentiation and integration, series and limits.

These can also be mixed. For instance:

- In algebraic topology you construct a structure of continious functions that you can combine in some specified way, and you study the arithmetical structure that arises (there are loads of ways to do it, and they all have different names like fundamental group, homology groups and cup product).
- In differential geometry you use analysis (differentiation) to analyse how curves curve, or to study the possible vector fields in a space (an example of a vector field on a space is the globe of the Earth, with details on how the wind is blowing on each point).

Comment: What about number theory? Isn't that like a mix of everything? Almost…?

Answer (score 0):

This is a very hard question to answer because the 3 areas you mentioned are humungous. There is many different subsections within. Furthermore tons of these subsections are connected with tons of the subsections from the other areas of study. Lie algebras and jet spaces are two topics usually studied in Geometry, but by no means exclusively. These areas study different types of manifolds, but a manifold is a topological space. Many of the problems in geometry depend on tools from topology and algebra. In fact all of these areas use tools from the others.

In my opinion and extremely broadly speaking,

Geometry generalizes the notions of Calculus to abstract spaces.

Topology is the study of topological spaces. There are many different ways to study topological spaces using different approaches (algebraic topology, differential topology...). Topology gives a deep and formal way to study shapes and familiar physical objects.

Abstract algebra, in it's most basic terms, studies groups rings and fields.

Comment: Yeah I have studied all these subjects at the undergraduate level so I understand them but I don't completely understand statements like I posted.

Answer (score 0):

Simply, Algebra means "binary operations". everywhere you have a binary operation(on a set) you have algebra. Thus algebra is everywhere!
Geometry is "distance". By Erlanger program, a geometry on a set M is a distance formula. Distance should have some specific properties. for instance in  Relativity we have a distance formula, therefore we have a geometry.
Analyses is geometry with a special distance. 
Topology is continuity. when you crumple a rubber ball, you change its geometry but don't change its topology. (Of course you should not break the ball)

Comment: And what about for example, unary, or ternary operations. It is not algebra?

Comment: Yes, this is algebra too. But binary operations are important. Group, Rings, Fields are basic notions in algebra and in such structure binary operation are.

Comment: All of them can be expressed via binary operations: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying

Answer (score -1):

Try these simpler words; Algebra is the use of simple equations and variables to solve a problem. Geometry uses these equations and variables and applies then with various theorems to shapes. Algebra II is more complex equations and can deal with several variables in one problem whilst general topology is based solely on set theory and concerns itself with structures of sets. Hope these basic mental sets help.

Comment: Thanks but I was not meaning elementary algebra when I posted. I was thinking along the lines of modern or abstract algebra.